# the right place to deserialize on Android

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm developing an Android app which stores a TreeSet object using serialization in a file. I need to serialize the object on close of my app and deserialize on launch because I need an access during a complete runtime. Unfortunately it's quite unpredictable on which activity the user will start/end so it's unclrear to me where are the right places to put this serialization and deserialization calls so that the object is available during the complete runtime.

thanks in advance for any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on how performance dependant your app is and how complex your serialization process is I'd read on startup in your main activities `onCreate()` and write everytime a value is being set. Simple and unefficient, but safe.